# How to get the count of values from firebase dataSnapshot?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my  `OpenActivity.class` where am reading the data from firebase realtime database, I want to get the number of counts of particular value.

my realtime database node looks like this,

```
-Notificationsss
   -ID
     -message1: "Hello"
     -notificationStatus: "Opened"
     -type1: "asada"



-Notificationsss
       -ID
         -message1: "Hello"
         -notificationStatus: "UnOpened"
         -type1: "asada"
```

I want to get the count of value "Unopened"

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Notificationssss");

        notificationList = new ArrayList<>();   

     mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            try {


      notificationList.clear();



        for (DataSnapshot notificationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            notification = notificationSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                            notificationList.add(notification);

                        }

                        NotificationList adapter = new NotificationList(OpenNotification.this,notificationList);
                        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not store metadata or a count for the number of read/writes that are performed on a property. To achieve this, you need to implment this logic yourself by adding a counter, that must be updated every time you read or write data from the database.

If you think that this counter can be updated by concurrent users, I highly recommend you to use [Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Is there any query to get the counts of value "Unopened" only with the help of datasnapshot.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You can achieve this very simply using transactions.